# PHP form is not sending out an email when my form is submitted on a live site

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to figure out why my form is not sending when it's in MAMP local host or hosted live on my site. Everything looks right to me but for whatever reason, I'm not getting an email sent to me.

This is my form:

```
<form action="assets/php/mail.php" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input required class="bg-athens-gray px-4" type="text" name="name" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="First Name" required>
        </div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input required class="bg-athens-gray px-4" type="email" name="email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your email address" required>
        </div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea required class="bg-athens-gray px-4" cols="10" rows="4" name="message" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        </div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" class="font-size-14 ltr-sp-2">
        </div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</form>
```

This is what's right after the body tag of my mail.php page, which is replicating most of the contact page. I'm using it to confirm that a form has been submitted while keeping the webpage looking the same.

```
<body>
    <?php
            $userName       = $_POST['name'];
            $userEmail      = $_POST['email'];
            $userMessage        = $_POST['message'];
            $to             = "myemail@websiteaddress.com";
            $subject        = "Email from contact page";
            $body           = "Information Submitted:";
            $body .= "\r\n Name: " . $userName;
            $body .= "\r\n Email: " . $userEmail;
            $body .= "\r\n Message: " . $userMessage;
            mail($to, $subject, $body);
    ?>
    ...
```

Comment: I have gone through other people's answers on this but haven't found the answer yet. I've tried different email addresses as well and that didn't work.

Comment: What are the hosting provider's requirements for this, if applicable? For example, a hosting provider may have a specific path to include Mail.php from per server.

Comment: Place your `mail()` function inside an `if/else`. If this goes to `if` with an echo'd message, then mail did its job. If it goes to `else/error`, then it failed and you need to find out why.